# Getting very large numbers using logistic regression

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic-regression, prediction

I'm trying to predict the gender for some samples that have missing values. I'm doing that using the gene expression.

So first I train the logistic regression model using the samples that don't have missing values (that have the value male or female). This is the data I'm using (called `mydata`) to train the model, and here in the `Gender` feature, the `1` are males and `0` are females:

```
structure(list(CA5B = c(30.8594477594147, 30.8773853294407, 31.5109543268185, 
29.852812443292, 31.9303544611987, 32.1541109784662, 32.6520127984013, 
32.9726252284503, 31.4152036112846, 32.6206677736732), DDX3X = c(35.25792, 
35.17134, 36.28966, 36.08013, 36.2734, 35.60448, 36.01073, 36.28618, 
35.42917, 35.85764), EIF1AX = c(32.12871, 31.99721, 33.5218, 
34.90091, 33.33981, 33.07818, 32.95223, 34.47241, 31.50087, 32.53821
), VAX2 = c(26.0371, 23.2217, 19.53356, 23.92908, 22.51166, 22.45692, 
23.62209, 19.53356, 19.53356, 19.53356), KLRC1 = c(30.35354, 
28.63985, 25.67501, 26.18108, 30.0377, 29.63008, 25.20041, 28.79883, 
30.04889, 31.12243), KLRC2 = c(30.69315, 29.72534, 23.88161, 
28.60153, 30.28375, 28.74612, 24.03185, 25.71121, 28.1028, 30.75633
), ARSD = c(31.6010966942421, 31.2081406187661, 32.525989520392, 
33.4006989772133, 31.8554455039159, 32.3438989185126, 32.103684088194, 
32.2785447752453, 32.028984695614, 31.5829276898759), DDX43 = c(29.90975, 
28.0152, 26.15494, 25.70774, 26.4806, 27.44477, 30.52285, 31.97889, 
31.50345, 26.90941), RPS4Y1 = c(35.94301, 36.79795, 38.03506, 
26.53381, 29.87951, 37.13222, 35.91265, 26.53172, 35.37051, 37.71164
), TRAPPC2 = c(31.73251, 32.12647, 32.91964, 33.16043, 32.28315, 
33.24194, 31.20461, 31.56589, 32.482, 34.21314), SNCG = c(28.78017, 
33.80945, 31.28264, 35.49992, 31.63203, 29.34577, 29.78785, 30.73165, 
29.9412, 26.04425), KDM6A = c(34.19294, 34.71109, 33.94433, 34.64027, 
34.93768, 34.25181, 34.2198, 34.88605, 33.38825, 34.8068), ZFX = c(33.84244, 
34.04817, 33.83408, 34.90102, 34.77175, 33.54326, 34.39611, 34.50292, 
33.27768, 33.87074), PNPLA4 = c(31.15101, 31.32295, 33.38545, 
34.34879, 30.98438, 32.77684, 31.26002, 32.36503, 31.15222, 32.12835
), KDM5C = c(33.6612, 34.3589, 33.50819, 34.56994, 34.46354, 
33.27832, 34.10299, 34.48084, 34.4775, 34.5186), SMC1A = c(34.18368, 
33.39101, 34.2632, 34.28327, 34.15166, 33.94223, 34.71688, 34.61705, 
33.99106, 33.76364), DDX3Y = c(34.14224, 34.8835, 34.7245, 26.66744, 
29.06797, 34.71189, 33.96947, 26.66531, 34.68055, 34.48187), 
    SYAP1 = c(32.03834, 32.42337, 32.51431, 33.51916, 32.82407, 
    32.4735, 32.49154, 33.51064, 31.29551, 31.83166), Gender = c(1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c("EA595454", "EA595500", 
"EA595522", "EA595529", "EA595597", "EA595624", "EA595632", "EA595635", 
"EA595647", "EA595654"), class = "data.frame")
```

###### Code:

```
split = sample.split(mydata, SplitRatio = 0.8)
train_reg = subset(mydata, split == "TRUE")
test_reg = subset(mydata, split == "FALSE")

logistic_model = glm(Gender~., data = train_reg,  family = binomial)
predict_reg = predict(logistic_model, test_reg, type = "response")
predict_reg = ifelse(predict_reg >0.5, 1, 0)
```

This produced AUC of 0.75 (on the test set). Not bad.

Then I take only the samples with the missing values of gender, and predict if they are male or female using the model.

```
pred = predict(logistic_model,mydata_NA_samples)
```

This is some of the results I get:

```
        Pt1             Pt10            Pt101            Pt103            Pt106             Pt11             Pt17             Pt18 
1548291146811975 -443770882316732  100625892356271  420508521495519 1756507132742650 -883868739619674 -262910227380331 2442533193074350 
             Pt2             Pt24             Pt26             Pt27             Pt28             Pt29              Pt3             Pt30 
 569411355627798 1699537030844227 -703783585812457 3495433064250008 -399805416449645 -339035064434972 2024260475793067  109885153661113 
            Pt31             Pt34             Pt36             Pt37             Pt38             Pt39              Pt4             Pt44 
-367070086585505 1330361581729001 1740587250736183 3489930082447853 -976790159879838 1751865170092986 -283113980482947 1902539723154004 
            Pt46             Pt47             Pt48             Pt49              Pt5             Pt52             Pt59             Pt62 
1412716353779596 1108256151592894 1074657527777400 -113959545517722  109187189819909  -57895108035064     792635620314  255566834903770 
            Pt65             Pt66             Pt67             Pt72             Pt77             Pt78             Pt79              Pt8 
 -46167159563698 -346701109064255   51185327645114 -795349064523229  244860086302444 4635500642717655  926236606202554  645399266579567 
            Pt82             Pt84             Pt85             Pt89              Pt9             Pt90             Pt92             Pt94 
-651113408988261 -641572344400162 -594901636707441 1514453985992888 -227744411687312  166300730517187 2842003327373200 2502780813663413
```

I mean, what is this? I'm supposed to get 0 or 1, and maybe some very small number that is close to 0, but this is very strange. I should mention that `mydata` and `mydata_NA_samples` have the exact same features, but of course just different samples. How could this happen in logistic regression, which in the first place should only return a binary result?

Thanks!

Comment: Add `type="response"` to the predict call on NA dataset.

Comment: @user2974951 I can't belive I forgot to add that. I appreciate you my friend.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `type="response"` in the second predict call.